# How to block extreme winds on a stormy planet?

Tags: science-based, physics, climate, geography, weather

Assume that you have a planet mostly covered in water (about 89% of the surface is water). There are a few connected continents in the middle of the planet. If the rotation of the planet is slow, say 200 Earth days for a full rotation, and is temperate in temperature, winds on the planet are extremely fast. Since the wind speeds might be too high for a regular human to survive without a spacesuit, **how would you make the planet survivable?**

The geography of the planet can be changed, like mountains, but the actual planetary characteristics cannot, such as the rotation. The problem I ran into with adding a ton of mountains is that it creates a rain shadow. I want the continents to be temperate with lots of rainfall, so that does not work. Furthermore, I do not know if the mountains would slowly erode away and lose effectiveness. Additionally, large technological structures are out of the question because the natives are at a Roman-esque time period.

**Map:**
[image]

**Clarifications:**

The planet must remain windy out in the ocean, I am only looking to reduce winds to survivable levels in the middle of the continents.

The islands up north preferably are windier than the mainlands, needing special protection, but still need to be liveable.

The planet in question also has two moons, creating huge tides.

**Any help is appreciated, thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Thick forests.**

[image: forest]

https://www.flocabulary.com/unit/tropical-rainforests/

Your trees are big and sturdy.  You can hear the wind howling high above you but the forest spans the continent and no wind penetrates the sides.

Comment: This is an absolutely perfect solution, I love the idea of ambient wind high above! But do you know if the trees/soil will survive high winds? Furthermore, how large of an area do the trees cover?

Comment: The forest evolved there.  There are edge specialists - whippy little trees that can tolerate wind.  Once they come up there are other trees that grow in their shelter, and so on.  The old growth forest has been standing for thousands of years and the soil has accumulated in its shade.  This forest is like the American forest used to be - a squirrel could go from the Atlantic to the Mississippi without ever touching the ground.